# recursion in view

Tags: python, django

I want to make this hierarchy:

```
      <ul id="red" class="treeview-red">
          <li><span>Item 1</span>
            <ul>
              <li><span>Item 1.0</span>
                <ul>
                  <li><span>Item 1.0.0</span></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><span>Item 1.1</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span>Item 2</span>
            <ul>
              <li><span>Item 2.0</span>
                <ul>
                  <li><span>Item 2.0.0</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span>Item 2.0.0.0</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item 2.0.0.1</span></li>
                  </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="open"><span>Item 3</span>
            <ul>
              <li class="open"><span>Item 3.0</span>
                <ul>
                  <li><span>Item 3.0.0</span></li>
                  <li><span>Item 3.0.1</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span>Item 3.0.1.0</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item 3.0.1.1</span></li>
                  </ul>

                </li>
                  <li><span>Item 3.0.2</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li><span>Item 3.0.2.0</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item 3.0.2.1</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item 3.0.2.2</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

with this model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent=models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

in views.py I've wrote this simple code to get categories:

```
def getCats(request):
    cats=Category.objects.all()
    str=u''
    str+='<li><span>Item 1</span><ul>'
    for cat in cats:
        str+=hiararchy(cat)
    str+=u'</ul></li>'
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(str),mimetype='application/json')

def hiararchy(cat):
    s=''
    if cat.parent is None or cat.parent==cat:
        s=cat.name
    else:
        s=cat.name
        return hiararchy(cat.parent)
    return s
```

I don't know how to get categories with that format,frankly I'm not very good at recursive functions.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use something like django-mptt or django-treebeard, which already have methods built-in to deal with template rendering.

Comment: I don't need to generate those numbers,It's just example,I will replace the name of categories.tnx

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether you want to show the numbers or not. If you're dealing with hierarchical relationships, there's a *metric ton* of things to consider and account for. There's already packages that deal with this problem, and *well*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I came up with this solution:

```
def getCats(request):
    cats=Category.objects.filter(parent=None)
    s=u'<ul id="red" class="treeview-red">'
    for cat in cats:
        s += hiararchy(cat,True)
    s+=u'</ul>'
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(s),mimetype='application/json')

def hiararchy(cat,flag):
    if cat.parent and flag:
        return hiararchy(cat.parent,True)
    else:
        if cat.children.count()>0:
            s=u'<li><a href="#" id="'+str(cat.pk)+'" class="cat">%s</a>'%(cat.name)
            for child in cat.children.all():
                s+=u'<ul>%s</li></ul></li>'%(hiararchy(child,False))
            return s
        else:
            return u'<li><a href="#" id="'+str(cat.pk)+'" class="cat">%s</a></li>'%(cat.name)
```

pay attention :
1)when a category don'e have parent it means it's the root node in tree
2)numbering in my example didn't implement in my code,I needed to replace the name of categories in place of those numbers

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you'll find this post useful: I asked a similar question a while back with recursion that looks a bit like yours

[Python Recursion through objects and child objects, Print child depth numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984513/python-recursion-through-objects-and-child-objects-print-child-depth-numbers)